# How to export data from hbase to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hbase, sqoop

How can I export data from hbase to SQL Server? Can I do it directly using some tools? I use sqoop to export data from SQL Server to hbase. But how can I use sqoop-export to export data from hbase to SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting data from HBase to RDBMS is not supported so far.

> One work around is you can export HBase data into a file in HDFS and
>   that can be exported into RDBMS.

For more information you can check [Sqoop1 vs Sqoop2](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-2-x/topics/cdh_ig_sqoop_vs_sqoop2.html)